# How to get the name of stored procedure within a package and a schema accessing a particular table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have used following query to get the procedure list but I am getting just the schema name and package name. If the TYPE Column returns PACKAGE BODY, then how to get the procedure name within the package accessing the table EXCEPTIONAL_INFO, please help.

```
SELECT * FROM All_DEPENDENCIES WHERE REFERENCED_NAME = 'EXCEPTIONAL_INFO';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this query:

```sql
    select owner, object_name, procedure_name
    from all_procedures 
    where object_name = 
      ( 
        SELECT name FROM All_DEPENDENCIES WHERE REFERENCED_NAME = 'EXCEPTIONAL_INFO' 
        and type='PACKAGE BODY' and rownum=1
      )
    ;
```

Comment: I don't know the schema also , I have to search in my entire database to find where a table is used so I can't simply put a filter on schema /object name . In the OP , I want schema.package_name.procedure_name

Comment: Now you want me to write the join for you?  I will edit my answer now.  Be aware that the subquery can return more than one row so I tested it with rownum=1 to find the first package that is referenced.

Comment: @sandman: ALL_DEPENDENCIES shows which package uses the table, but not which procedure in the package. Your query shows *all* procedures of the package, regardless if they use the table or not.

Comment: SELECT A.OWNER,A.OBJECT_NAME,A.PROCEDURE_NAME FROM ALL_PROCEDURES A ,All_DEPENDENCIES B WHERE 
 A.OBJECT_NAME=B.NAME AND A.OWNER=B.OWNER AND B.REFERENCED_NAME = 'EXCEPTIONAL_INFO' AND B.TYPE='PACKAGE BODY'
 AND A.PROCEDURE_NAME IS NOT NULL

Comment: Is query fine ?

Answer (score 0):

You can scan the source texts of the packages. I've used the view `DBA_SOURCE` because I believe `ALL_SOURCE` shows only the code of procedures I can execute.

```
CREATE TABLE exceptional_info (i INT);

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE p IS
  PROCEDURE a;
  PROCEDURE b(table_name VARCHAR2);
END p;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY p IS
  PROCEDURE a AS 
    n NUMBER; 
  BEGIN 
    SELECT count(*) INTO n FROM exceptional_info;  
  END a;

  PROCEDURE b(table_name VARCHAR2) AS
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE '||table_name;
  END b;
END;
/
```

You can find the packages with `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` and scan the source text of those dependencies:

```
SELECT owner, type, name, s.line, s.text
  FROM dba_dependencies d
  LEFT JOIN dba_source s USING (owner, name, type)
 WHERE d.referenced_name = 'EXCEPTIONAL_INFO'
   AND upper(s.text) like '%EXCEPTIONAL_INFO%';

OWNER  TYPE         NAME  LINE TEXT
SO     PACKAGE BODY P       10     SELECT count(*) INTO n FROM exceptional_info;
```

You need to go up from line 10 to find the name of the procedure in the source text. I'm too lazy to code that now.

However, this method will find only static text. It cannot find `PROCEDURE b` in the example, which also can modify table exceptional_info, without having the name hard coded. Do you need to catch those usages, too?

Comment: all_procedures shows procedures within packages so you don't have to scan all_source

Comment: @sandman, yes, but you don't know which of those procedures in the package are accessing the table  EXCEPTIONAL_INFO

Comment: Good point. The query would then require a bit more work. Which is more effort than I would care to do right now :)

Comment: I do not have to Procedure b as you mentioned , my work is done from your query , thanks

Comment: Good job. That's one of the advantages of static code. Just make sure you find upper and lower case spellings of the tablename.